# Query a parent-children entities with one-many relationships and retrieve children records based on values in the parent record using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a Asp.net MVC application which has 3 classes; Event, Modification, FieldHistory. Events has a one-many with Modifications, and Modifications also has one-many relationship with FieldHistory.

Event class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

Modification class:

```
public class Modification
{
    public int ModificationId { get; set; }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

    public string ModificationStatus { get; set; }
}
```

FieldHistory class:

```
public class FieldHistory
{

    public int FieldHistoryId { get; set; }

    public int ModificationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Modification Modification { get; set; }

    public int PropValId { get; set; }

    public int KeyFieldId { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

In one of the Index actions I am returning an IEnumerable of Modifications to the view and present them as list items in the index page.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var modifications = _applicationDbContext.Modifications.Include(m 
=> m.Event)
                                .Include(m => m.ItemType)
                                .Include(m => m.ModificationType)
                                .OrderByDescending(m => m.CurrentUserId);


        return View(await modifications.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I would like to extend this query so that now I will also show Modifications together with one of its child records based on the ModificationStatus field of the Modification entity. For example if the modificationstatus is "Creating" or "Created" then load the FieldHistory that has PropValId of 1, otherwise if status is "Processing" or "Approved" then load FieldHistory of PropValId of 2 as its child. So in a list item I should have all 3 entities in a record: Event, Modification, FieldHistory

I am a just a beginner in Linq and hope that this can be another big step for me.

Comment: Do you want a conditional ef query for include or do you want to have filtered children

Comment: It would be good to have an example of each as I do not really know the difference between the two. They both sound appropriate to what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a direct way to tie in the ModificationStatus with PropValId, so instead just using what you conveyed above and obviously you'd have to supply the additional rules if there are more... also only going to take the *First* one of other object types but you can change that if you need all associated ones...

I'm picking up from your variable modifications as defined above, and of course assuming the names of the tables in your DbContext containing the other objects:

```
    var trios = modifications.Select(m => new { Modification = m, // select the modification obj itself
       FieldHistory = _applicationDbContext.FieldHistories.FirstOrDefault(fh =>
           fh.ModificationId == m.ModificationId && // I am assuming this is required
           fh.PropValId == (new List<string> {"Creating", "Created"}.Contains(m.ModificationStatus) ? 1 : 2)),
       Event = _applicationDbContext.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EventId == m.EventId)
    }).ToList();
```

This will return what you're looking for. If you want, you can create a class, e.g.:

```
public class Trio {

    public Modification Modification { get; set; }
    public FieldHistory FieldHistory { get; set; }
    public Event Event { get; set; }

    public Trio (Modification modification, FieldHistory fieldHistory, Event @event)
    {
        this.Modification = modification; 
        this.FieldHistory = fieldHistory;
        this.Event = @event;
    }
}
```

Then change to:

```
    var trios = modifications.Select(m => new Trio(m, // select the modification obj itself
       _applicationDbContext.FieldHistories.FirstOrDefault(fh =>
           fh.ModificationId == m.ModificationId && // I am assuming this is required
           fh.PropValId == (new List<string> {"Creating", "Created"}.Contains(m.ModificationStatus) ? 1 : 2)),
       _applicationDbContext.Events.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EventId == m.EventId)
    )).ToList();
```